# Swift - Problem with ForEach statement while structure is empty

Tags: swift, struct, foreach

I have a forEach statement that illiterates through a struct containing meal entries. If the struct is empty, I would like to display alternative Text.

My issue is when the array is empty, I receive the following error when compiling

> Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Meal'

```
  let mealEntrysDinner: [String] = [
        
    ]



 Section(header:Text("Dinner")){
               ForEach(mealEntrysDinner, id: \.self){ meal in
                   if(mealEntrysDinner.isEmpty == true){
                       Text("Arr Empty")
                   }
                   else{
                       EntryRow(meal:meal)
                   }
                  
               }
                
            }
```

Meal Structure below:

```
struct Meal: Identifiable, Hashable{
    var id = UUID()
    var mealName: String
    var calories: String
    var quantity: Int
    var amount: String
    var protein:  String
}
```

EntryRow

```
struct EntryRow: View {
    var meal: Meal
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            Text(meal.mealName)
                            Text(meal.amount)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                           
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Text(meal.calories)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've defined `mealEntrysDinner: [String]` -- are you sure you don't want it to be `[Meal]`?

Comment: There is no point in checking if the array is empty _inside_ the loop since that code will never be executed when the array is empty. Move the if/else outside of the loop

Comment: This is SwiftUI. You should add the SwiftUI Tag. (Also `ForEach` (upper case) and `forEach` (lower case) are different. Your title and code says `ForEach`, but the body of your question says `forEach`. I'm assuming you mean the SwiftUI `ForEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.

First, it looks like you want `mealEntrysDinner` to be `[Meal]`, not `[String]` -- otherwise, as you've discovered, the types don't match and you can't use `EntryRow`.

Secondly, you have something out-of-order with your `if` clause -- it should be *outside* the `ForEach`:

```
Section(header:Text("Dinner")){
    if mealEntrysDinner.isEmpty {
        Text("Arr Empty")
    } else {
        ForEach(mealEntrysDinner) { meal in
            EntryRow(meal:meal)
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the `ForEach` only gets displayed if `mealEntrysDinner` has elements.

Comment: Thanks! By switching the [String] to [Meal] on the array I was able to pass the if else statement in. Thanks again.